# Line integrals over smooth curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

While learning the concept of a line integral over a curve, I was told that the curve over which the line integral is to be computed has to be smooth. The line integral is given by, $\int_{a}^{b} f(x, y, z) |\vec{v(t)}| \mathrm dt$. Does the condition "smooth curve" arise from the fact that velocity $\vec v(t)$ is undefined at sharp turns and jumps?

Comment: It really only needs to be piecewise smooth.

Comment: @amd I do understand that. We break the integral down into finite segments and evaluate each over smooth curves. What hit my mind was, given a curve that has finite jumps and sharp turns, why can we not evaluate over the entire curve at once. It was then that I thought about velocity.